# How to capture paste event anywhere on page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having looked at other stack overflow questions and on Google, I haven't been able to find an answer to this.

**Background:**
I'm currently re-writing a jquery application in React. Previously I was just adding a paste event listener to the body of the page. That seemed to allow me to capture any paste event the user would do.

**Questions:**

1. In React, with the code below in my App.js file, on initial load of the page it doesn't allow me to capture paste events. Only after clicking somewhere on the page does it then work when I paste. I realise I could just have an input and an onPaste attribute, but I need to be able to capture automatically.
2. In terms of passing the pasted text down the component tree, with the ability to edit the text from a lower component, am I right in thinking it's best to pass a callback as a prop down from the top-level component so the state is always updated using a function in the top-level component?

Currently this is what I have:

```
// App.js

import TopBar from "./components/TopBar/TopBar";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper/Wrapper";
import AppContainer from "./components/AppContainer/AppContainer";

function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      onPaste={(e) => setInputText(e.clipboardData.getData("Text"))}
      className="App"
    >
      <TopBar />
      <Wrapper>
        <h2>New Flashcard</h2>
        <AppContainer inputText={inputText} setInputText={setInputText} />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your listener will only work when the specific `div` is focused, therefore it works on the second attempt. Instead, add the listener to `body` element or `window` object:

```
function Component() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
      setInputText(e.clipboardData.getData("text"));
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("paste");
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{inputText}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit Paste Listener]

2. > am I right in thinking it's best to pass a callback

No, it depends on the depth, please read about [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) and research on an anti-pattern called ["props-drilling"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/).

Comment: it seems like the `window.removeEventListener` is not following the api as specified on the mdn web docs:

`removeEventListener(type, listener)`
`removeEventListener(type, listener, options)`
`removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)`.


So if i'm not mistaken this answer has a potential memory leak issue due to not properly removing the event listener added in the beginning of the useEffect.